Ethernet features like pole-reversial lane-reversal
I am using the LAN7340 and need to mount it on the back of an existing hardware design. Unfortunately, this results in the MDIX channels being reversed and the polarity being flipped. In PCIe connections, there are features like "Pole Reversal" and "Lane Reversal" – are there any similar features available with this PHY? Or there are general features in Ethernet like this?
The standard wiring is as follows:
MDIX_A → J{1/2}
MDIX_B → J{3/6}
MDIX_C → J{4/5}
MDIX_D → J{7/8}
Would it also be possible to wire it as follows?
MDIX_D → J{1/2}
MDIX_C → J{3/6}
MDIX_B → J{4/5}
MDIX_A → J{7/8}
